# Bow to change stand-alone toolbar colors programmatically?

Tags: android, toolbar

I have a stand-alone `Toolbar` and I'm trynig to change the background color by using this code:

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor();
```

But it expects an integer and I have no idea how to use a color as an integer! I searched and find, It can be changed if it was a `Toolbar` as an `ActionBar`.
I think It should be a way for stand-alone toolbar, too... Any idea?

Comment: Use `0xAARRGGBB` if you know the hex value, it's alpha,red,green,blue.

Comment: getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary); try this.

Comment: @Elvisjames thanks for your comment, it really helped!

Comment: @SurenderKumar thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I mistake not actually you want to know how an integer reperesnts a color, Android colors have these values: **Alpha**, **Red**, **Green** and **Blue** (**ARGB**) and every one of them are considered as a 8 bit value so you need a variable with 4x8bits preserved size and `int` type in java is the proper option for you.

For more readability for human sometimes we use **hex** numbers for color representation "**0xAARRGGBB**", Something like this:

```
//an opaque blue
//alpha = FF
//Red = 00
//Green = 00
//Blue = FF
int color = 0xFF0000FF
```

Then you can set your desired color like this:

```
toolbar.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(color));
```

Or this:

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Comment: @eli.m93 My pleasure, If any of posted answers is helpful accept it please.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to set background color to your `Toolbar`

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundColor((Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
```

**OR**

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundColor((Color.RED));
```